# Diagonal stripped pattern with css gradients behaves weird

Tags: css, gradient

I've followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585110/css3-1px-diagonal-lines-gradient) to create a diagonal pattern in some elements of my website. However, the result is different in each element.

For example my buttons work as expected:
[image: Diagonal gradient as expected]

However, when I try to apply it to other elements such as: 
[image: Diagonal gradient weird]

Lines seem to collapse erratically and the result is not the same.

My css code is

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(29,178,216,0.3), rgba(29,178,216,0.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 3px);
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see if this helps [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(29,178,216,0.3), rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 50%);
background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(29,178,216,0.3), rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 50%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(29,178,216,0.3), rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 50%);
background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(29,178,216,0.3), rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 50%);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(29,178,216,0.3), rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(29,178,216,0.3) 50%);

-webkit-background-size: 4px 4px;
   -moz-background-size: 4px 4px;
     -o-background-size: 4px 4px;
        background-size: 4px 4px;

/* Background size must be an even number! */
```